# why the execution of the follwing function gives Runtime Errors: Abort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT)?

Tags: algorithm, dictionary, runtime-error, c++14, sigabrt

```
   **There is a structure in my program**

    #include<bits/stdc++.h> 
    using namespace std;
    #define N 1000005 
    #define MAX 1e18 
    // Vector to store powers greater than 3 
    vector<long long int> powers; 

    // vector to store perfect squares 
    vector<long long int> squares;
```

```
    void computation()
    { 
     unordered_map<long long int,long long int> mp;
     unordered_map<long long int,long long int> ms;
    squares.push_back(1); 
    ms[1]=1;
    for (long long int i = 2; i <N; i++)  
    { 
        // pushing squares

        squares.push_back(i * i); 
        ms[i*i]=1;
             if (ms[i]==1) 
                continue; 

        long long int temp = i; 

        // run loop until some 
        // power of current number 
        // doesn't exceed MAX 
        while (i * i <= MAX / temp)  
        { 
            temp *= (i * i); 
             if(mp[temp]==0){
            powers.push_back(temp);
            mp[temp]=1;
             }

        } 
    } 
    sort(powers.begin(),powers.end());
    sort(squares.begin(),squares.end());
    }
```

**in main function after computation function call any operation gives sig error**

```
  int main(){

  computation();

  return 0;

  }
```

**How to rewrite this correctly with using map?** 
***Sorry, if this question had already been asked, I could not understand while looking through them.***

Comment: error persist even if i used unsigned long long int

Answer (score 1):

Corrected missing parentheses in the line:

```
while(i * i <= (MAX / temp)){
```

Still, for the value of N ranging to 10^5, its powers go beyond the range of 10^10 and 10^20s, that's why it is aborted after the tolerance limit of the compiler. Currently, there is no data type that can handle that many values in C++. See execution times and outputs. Try optimizing your code or find another algorithm for your problem. For small values of N such as N = 10005, the program is executed successfully.

TIO Compiler: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVNda9swFH2WfsWlfZiddE28MSjYLuwHrI9jUEpx5OtE1JY0faRjIb89u5KdkLT0YQbL6J5zz/20MObzWojD4Voq0YcWq5X0buF8K@bz2809cB6cVGtQzYDONAKBsJLz6xY7qRAeoFjS8w1Olh/ff0GBxR3wxQJ@ovDagtfkpi2C0a9oHawtNh7JvmkUfAW@TbSq1xQpHVL5@4lcUg6ktH2rhLYjE7jfobHoPtKY4CjCt1q2IPRggm@81CrLd8BZUNq2aLF9Hhpz6X7zRmww5f/xHfGnDG5NcJvnVSNesiKndNjgHounuiBGR3VlF64goYYvJX2qBzrn83zHGaMuRJE4jkmUk/W9voQZyBQjBpEzOYZhsoMsGp7qusgjyoRWXqqAsT2MXabgcTCUhRwxim2DIlQbCOTUg9MDwpRVHBToDkSwFslXhWFFlhFtNTr1yQP@EYht2g8CXjeyRxhzhaqGLNoXKWqe5sJYymBWw3lBVEQ2mMcIURnL1Bc2LspZB5JKLJmduKkD@1jKnnTi67T12eS6wrWkfbiZrqjaLI8CiXPs8JF0vJ9YNMAsTa1e0rSqScTJv5jl4/h47HXwUFXTVtMU4uUKruhnOmGk2L/XO8b7QHCCLxSpPh4VhiZmvIsRztaeQlj0wSpYlnx/OPwD)

Ideone: [Demo - Ideone online compiler](https://ideone.com/GvGWRC)

Another solution you could try is store integers in string formats, for large string size, that will cost huge computational time, but can be easily optimized for multiplication in terms of additions and small-multiplications.

Comment: what if i used this algorithm??

Comment: in above link .....i have seperatly find out only squares till 10^18 in o(10^9) but still gives segabrt

Comment: just please tell me how i should store squares upto 10^18 efficently

Comment: @rocking Your link https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/jvCHaChm8p has compiler errors.

Comment: @rocking The above program (written in the answer), in fact, runs efficiently just compiler is not able to print such large number of huge values, that's it. For verification, it can print values for odd places.

Comment: Or use freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout); in program to store all output values into a file named output.txt